# How can I change the line height of the body element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that change `lineHeight` of body (I need to change line height of all elements):

```
if (document.body.style.lineHeight == "")
{ 
    document.body.style.lineHeight = "1.0em";
}
document.body.style.lineHeight = parseFloat(document.body.style.lineHeight) + (0.4) + "em";
```

If the document hasn't any `line-height` in it's css this code works perfectly and all line height of elements will be increased,
BUT there is strange behavior in some case:

1. the `document.body.style.lineHeight == ""` is always true even if the body in css has `line-height`!!!
2. if any of the elements has `line-height` in CSS this code will fail to change line height. i can get `document.body.style.lineHeight` value and i can see that it increase BUT nothing change in document! (no visual effect)

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Point 1: the `element.style` object reads directly from the element's `style` attribute, so it is unaware of styles set in CSS. To read those, you need `getComputedStyle` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: _if the body in css_ you mean in css-file, or in _style_ attribute?

Comment: @Grundy, the css file

Comment: so see comment @Utkanos above :-) also it would be great if you can provide code snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: @Utkanos: so, if i get the style with `var elem1 = document.body;
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);`, then how i can change the line height?

Comment: as for second question: nested elements which has _line-height_ in CSS ignore _body.style.lineHeight_ because it have a more specific selector, so it override inherited value from body style

Comment: You set it as you currently are - it's just your reading mechanism that's erroneous.

Comment: @Grundy, you are right, do you have any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: i'm not sure what you goal at end: anyway rules in _style_ attribute have highest precedency, so you can simple manual set needed styles in all needed elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need `window.getComputedStyle()` (or just `getComputedStyle()`) to retrieve the actually applied style of an element, because `element.style` will only return the contents of the HTML `style` attribute.

Note however, that will not be the literal value you assigned it (like `1.5em`), but the equivalent in pixels (`1em = 16px` by the way). The returned value will also not be a number, but a string containing the suffix `px`.

Also note that the default value will not be `""`, but `"normal"`.
But it could also be `"initial"` or `"inherit"`, so instead of checking its actual value, I suggest just checking whether the string ends in `px`.

So your code should probably look like:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
if (style.lineHeight.match(/px$/) === null)
{ 
    document.body.style.lineHeight = "1.0em";
}
else
{
    document.body.style.lineHeight = (parseFloat(style.lineHeight) / 16) + (0.4) + "em";
}
```

Also: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j94gvnoe/1/).

And last, note that if you specify a percentage as line height, there is no way to retrieve that value (other than parsing `$('style').innerHTML` yourself of course), you will only get the pixel equivalent at the time your function runs.

---

As for your question how to apply the line height to all elements, simply inject a `<style>` tag in head, containing CSS like:

```
*
{
    line-height: 1.0em !important;
}
```

So the snippet above would look something like this:

```
var tag = document.createElement('style');
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
if (style.lineHeight.match(/px$/) === null)
{
    tag.innerHTML = '* { line-height: 1.0em !important; }';
}
else
{
    tag.innerHTML = '* { line-height: ' + (parseFloat(style.lineHeight) / 16 + 0.4) + 'em !important; }';
}
document.head.appendChild(tag);
```

Of course this will not work if there are more specific selectors with `!important` already, but otherwise it will even override inline style attributes.

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j94gvnoe/3/).

Comment: as Grundy said "nested elements which has line-height in CSS ignore body.style.lineHeight" , do you have any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: I suggest injecting a `<style>` tag into head. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a program which accepts user input as the line height, and then implements it onto the text area/placeholder on clicking a button, you can try this:

HTML:

```
<input id = "lspace" placeholder = "Line Spacing">
</input>

<button id = "aplspace" onclick = "aplspace()"> Apply Line Spacing 
</button>

<textarea id = "tarea"> Your Text 
</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#lspace {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#aplspace {
  height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 0);
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#tarea {
  height: 400px;
  width: 1415px;
}
```

JS:

```
function aplspace() {
  var lspace = document.getElementById("lspace").value;
  lspace = Number(lspace);
  document.getElementById("tarea").style.lineHeight = lspace + "px";
}
```